# Is there any way to view logs for AdHoc apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

When running apps in debugging mode one can simply see the logs and their `println()` calls straight from xCode.

I want to test some things in a production environment, and hence want to see my logs for the app I signed with an AdHoc provisioning profile. Is there any way to achieve this? How?

Answer (score 7):

In XCode 7, firstly, connect your device with your Mac, then open XCode -> Windows -> Devices.
[image]

Choose device -> Your device (which you want to look LOG).
Look at the bottom, have a small arrow, touch it to see RUNTIME LOG of device.

[image]

Comment: I don't see a small arrow

Comment: Nevermind, I see it, but I guess you can't see println in production.

Comment: Why you use println(), it's not the Log system of Apple, it's C function, it just show in command line. You should use NSLog() instead.

Comment: Is this also works for iOS 10 devices? Because it is not working in my case but it is working for iOS 9 devices.

Answer (score 0):

@**david**, For that you have to set **AlertView** Wherever you want to NSLOG,

Using Simple **UIAlertView** you can check your Important Log in iPhone Alert Screen, this is good Idea , you can use it. & after **testing App** , you have to **Remove** it.

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LOG" 
                                                        message:@"Dee dee doo doo." 
                                                        delegate:self 
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Tested" 
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
```